# Checking for failed image load

Tags: javascript, jquery, error-handling, loading-image

In the code below, I'm appending an image tag to a div. When the image is done loading (successfully), I'd like to run other functions before changing the page.

```
var $img = $("<img src='https://www.example.com/path' />").on('load', function() {
         console.log('img loaded');
         //do other stuff
         window.location = "otherpage.com";
         return true;
    });

    $(".imgContainer").append($img);
```

This working perfectly in the case where the image actually exists at the URL provided, or when it isn't blocked. (In my case, I'm getting `net::ERR_TUNNEL_CONNECTION_FAILED` errors when the image is appended due to my network proxy settings. On other networks, it works fine.)

**My question is**, how can I test for `404 (Not Found)` or `net::ERR_TUNNEL_CONNECTION_FAILED` errors in the .on('load') callback?

Tried checking the `responseText, textStatus, req` params in the callback, but obviously since the img is never loaded, the callback is never called. CORS not enabled.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `on('error', handler)` for catching 404

```
var $img = $("<img src='https://www.example.com/path' />").on('load', function() {
     console.log('img loaded');

}).on('error', function(event){

      console.log('img failed to load');
      console.log(event)
})
```